# What may I reference to learn Tanach chapters by topic?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach

What may I refer to to learn where to locate verses or sections in the Tanach by topic? Preferably one of our own sources rather than a Christian one because the interpretations of the Tanach need to be Jewish.

Comment: For Chumash I don't have on me to confirm but I believe the Living Torah by Rav Aryeh Kaplan has a topical index? Maybe even the Artscroll Stone Chumash?

Comment: @robev The Stone Chumash does have an index indeed. The Living Torah has a very detailed table of contents which lists topics of each parasha in great detail

Comment: Try also the מקבילות במקרא on Alhatorah.org

Comment: [Maybe this](https://www.sefaria.org/topics), although it is not just tanach.

Comment: Not a Jewish resource, but allows you to search by topic http://www.openbible.info/topics/

Comment: Tanach on the daf may serve as a good resource .

Answer (score 0):

Besides the handy suggestions in the comments namely Stone Chumash-Index and Living Torah-Index and -TOC..

..maybe consider a Concordance?

Some concordances are listed here
https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4584-concordance

Also Jastrow's dictionary has a good amount of Tanakh citations

https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP wants some kind of index to verses arranged by topic, not a new way to refer to a given verse.

Comment: @magicker72 oic, fixing..